# Delete all characters between text1 and (text2 or end of line)

Tags: sed

Line 1     :  `StartHere Word1 EndHere`

Line 2     :  `StartHere Word2`

should be

Line 1     :   `StartHereEndHere`

Line 2     :   `StartHere`

as u can see in this example, not always we have 'EndHere', some times it will be the end of the line, and I am using sed( and sed really hates '\n' i guess)

```
sed -i -e 's/\(StartHere\).*\(EndHere\)/\1\2/'
```

This one works for the first line.
So how should I treat the second case?
Ps: I am working on a file here.

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples of input and expected output. bla_bla and xxx mentioning will not give us clear picture of your actual requirement, so kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: should this be a greedy delete? Eg. what if you have a line `abc Start efg Start klm End pqr End rst`. Which result do you want? (1) `abc StartEnd rst` (2) `abc Start efg StartEnd rst` (3) `abc StartEnd pqr End rst` (4) `abc Start efg StartEnd pqr End rst`

Comment: I am sure here that the word that i am deleting after is there only once per line.

Comment: i just want a way to detect both the 'EndHere' word or end of the line, so that i don't end up deleting 'EndHere'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for GNU sed:

```
sed 's/EndHere/&\n/g; s/\(StartHere\)[^\n]*\(EndHere\|$\)/\1\2/g; s/\n//g' <<EOF
StartHere Word1 EndHere
StartHere Word2
StartHere Word2 EndHere something else
something else StartHere Word2 EndHere something else
EOF
```

outputs:

```
StartHereEndHere
StartHere
StartHereEndHere something else
something else StartHereEndHere something else
```

> I am sure here that the word that i am deleting after is there only once per line

Then you could:

```
sed 's/\(StartHere\).*\(EndHere\)/\1\2/; t; s/\(StartHere\).*$/\1/'
```

The `t` command will end processing of the current line if the last `s` command was successful. So... it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sed`, you could do it with Perl, which supports [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Using the example you gave in your comment:

```
$ echo "oooo StartHere=Yo9897 EndHereYo" \
  | perl -pe 's/(StartHere) (?: .*(EndHere) | .*(?!EndHere) )/$1$2/x'
```

would output "oooo StartHereEndHereYo".

`(?!...)` is a "negative lookahead"

The Perl's `x` regex option allows using spaces in the regex to make it (slightly) more readable

Comment: NOt working:  echo "oooo StartHere=Yo9897 EndHereYo" | sed -E 's/(StartHere).*?(EndHere|$)/\1\2/'       ==>   oooo StartHere

Comment: @aminezawix : Do you mean that you also want to delete anything before "StartHere"? If so, add `.*?` at the start of the regex. But if you also want to delete anything after "EndHere", you may indeed need 2 regexes.

Comment: @aminezawix : Or use Perl instead of `sed`. See revised answer.

Comment: `?(EndHere|$)` och, is the `?` a typo? sed doesn't have lookarounds The `?` is funny there, my testing shows it acts as `(.*)?` - it optionally matches everything, ie. the `?` is applied on `.*` I believe the `?` could just be removed.

Comment: @KamilCuk: No, it's `.*?`, a non-greedy match. But I didn't check if sed's extended regexes support it. They indeed don't support lookarounds.

Comment: `a non-greedy match` Och, I do not think that's possible (that easily :p ) in sed. I think it doesn't.  `sed -E 's/(StartHere).*?(EndHere|$)//' <<<'StartHere Word1 EndHere StartHere Word1 EndHere'` removes whole line, doesn't stop on the first match. The `.*?` optionally matches everything. (You would have to `sed -E 's/EndHere/&\n/g;s/(StartHere)[^\n]*(EndHere|$)//;s/\n//g' <<<'StartHere Word1 EndHere StartHere Word1 EndHere'` :D)

Comment: i don't care about the "before" here, as i said, i need to remove everything between "start" and "end", and if there is no "end" word , then delete all after "start"

Comment: i think it is not possible with sed, maybe.

Comment: @KamilCuk: thanks for your comments. I removed my wrong sed solution.

Comment: But... `sed -E 's/(StartHere).*(EndHere|$)/\1\2/'` is fine :p

Comment: @KamilCuk: not quite. That sed also removed "EndHere" if it was followed by something. So I prefered removing that half-solution.